# wrap_newBundle not available SWIG & webpay

Tags: php, swig, php-extension

I want to setup `webpay` on my local

1. Installed SWIG
2. Added `webpay` extension to `php.ini`

Then I tried to execute the `test.php` it shows the following error:

```
--------error while opening file [libwebpayclient.so]--------
<html>
<p> Starting webpay Transaction </p>
 wrap_newBundle not available
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you restarted you're web server after changing the php.ini file ?

Comment: @poelinca yes, I restarted my apache.

Answer (score 9):

Check to see if the library libwebpayclient.so is missing any dependencies:

Use the following check to check the dependencies (correct the path to suit your environment):

```
ldd /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/libwebpayclient.so
```

I had this same problem and discovered that libwebpayclient.so library has some precompiled dependencies on libssl.so.6 and libcrypto.so.6.
To work around this I just created some links to the current version of these files and everything worked  (correct the path and library versions to suit your environment).

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.6
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.6
```

Reference:
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/762312

Answer (score 0):

I run on the similar issue and get this resolved by **ldd libwebpayclient.so** and finding out that libssl.so.6 and libcrypto.so.6 is missing.

In Centos 6, in case you didnt find the libssl.so.6 and libcrypto.so.6, you just need to do **yum install openssl098e**.